# how to configure to access whoami in usr/bin/ inlinux

Tags: linux, sudoers

I want to configure /etc/sudoers file to allow access to a user named 'user1' to access /usr/bin/whoami file without any password. How can I do this. below are few modification which I done in the sudoers file.

```
user1   ALL=/usr/bin/whoami
user1   ALL=/usr/bin/mount
```

but when I try a below from user1

```
/root/usr/bin/whoami
```

then it says permission denied, then I try it with sudo as below

```
sudo /root/usr/bin/whoami
```

then it ask for password for user1 as below

```
[sudo] password for user1:
```

then after giving password for user1 it says

```
sudo: /root/usr/bin/whoami: command not found
```

Please tell me where I am wrong. Also please tell me how can I give permission for particular user on particular file with password and without password (both ways)

Comment: why call /root/usr/bin/whoami if you want to call /usr/bin/whoami ?

Comment: because without any privileges in sudoers file for user1 when I try /usr/bin/whoami, then it execute ant give the name of user1. mean it was executed locally by the user folder. But I want from root usr folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the `root` portion:

```
sudo /usr/bin/whoami
```

If you don't wan't any password, change your `sudoers` entry to:

```
user1   ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/whoami
```